# My game shows white textures using LIBGDX and AdMob

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I have succefully add and admob ad to my game. But the first time i load it, and only the first time, after i lock the device or go to home when i open again the game the textures are all white rectangles but the game is still running and i can hear the sounds and the actors are still working correctly but the ad is showing just fine.

PD. I just discovered that it only happens if i open the game just after installing it. If i finish the instalation, close the installation wizzard(?) and then open normaly the game the problem does not happen.

I don´t know whats is the reason of this.

My code is as it follows:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
private AdView adView;
RelativeLayout layout;
View gameView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    // Create the layout
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    gameView = initializeForView(new MyGame(), false);

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("MY ID");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build());

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    //adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.me.Prototipo_Bombas"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" /><application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape"       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|s    mallestScreenSize" />

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

If i lock the device or go to home the sounds are still working.
After closing the game the next time that i open it everything is fine. I don't know why it happens once.

I hope someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: have you tried  to remove admob and then see if problem still persist??

Comment: I just did. You are right, it seems that the problem was there before i add the "ad banner".

Comment: how are you using assets in your game. Are they static??

Comment: I am using a static AssetManager. Could this be the problem?. I stated it like this: public AssetManager MANAGER = new AssetManager();

Comment: I made a mistake up there it is stated like this: public static final AssetManager MANAGER = new AssetManager();

Comment: try making your assets class singleton.

Answer (score 0):

LibGdx#initialiseForView sets the ContentView. You are then calling setContentView again later  in onCreate. setContentView should only be called once. That is your problem.